# UIWebView play HTML5 video full screen, touch won't be recognized anymore

Tags: ios, swift, video, uiwebview

I used a perfectly normal `UIWebView` to show a youtube page, and tap a video to play it. After the app went into full screen and start playing the video, the app won't respond to touches anymore. The video all played fine, I just won't be about the tap the screen to show video control.

```
self.browser.frame = self.view.bounds // browser is an instance of UIWebView
self.browser.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: self.url))
```

The webpage loads and respond to touches just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out. It was due to a bug in https://github.com/icanzilb/EasyAnimation pod. fbef368eb157936e4c7df98189908852b7b37c75 commit fixed this bug. So after upgrade, everything worked just fine!